# how to give drag functionaly to a JFame with no titleBar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, drag

i m creating a JFrame with four buttons in its titleBar.

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("custom JFrame with 4 buttons in title");
frame.setUndecorated(true);

JPanel button_panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
JButton button_1=new JButton("+");
JButton button_2=new JButton("↑");
JButton button_3=new JButton("-");
JButton button_4=new JButton("system tray");

button_panel.add(button_1);
button_panel.add(button_2);
button_panel.add(button_3);
button_panel.add(button_4);

frame.getContentPane().add(button_panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

now, i have a JFrame with four buttons in its titlebar.

but, how to give drag functionality to this custom JFrame?

Comment: How do you want the JFrame to be moved? Something like clicking anything in the fame, and then dragging the mouse?

Comment: no.. only the top button_panel for dragging purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a java swing frame movable and setUndecorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046824/making-a-java-swing-frame-movable-and-setundecorated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it the only solution?

Well, the only solution that I know of is to use MouseListeners.

For a more general solution you can check out [Moving Windows](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) which allows you to make any Swing component dragable.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Mac OS X? A Mac-specific solution is this:

```
frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drag a JFrame by it's contents by setting up the MouseListener appropriately. [This post](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Dragandmoveaframefromitscontentarea.htm) has an example.

Comment: @Lokesh this is the easiest I can think of. Did you have a different approach in mind that you wanted to try?

Comment: @@Bala R can we extract titlbar component from JFrame UI and add one more Jbutton into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the offset between mouse position and components location on screen (components upper left corner), this is the easiest solution:

```
private class DragListener extends MouseAdapter {

   @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override mousepressed and mousedragged methods as shown:

```
private int tx, ty;
private void titlebar_mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
{
    tx= m.getX();
    ty=m.getY();
}
private void titlebar_mouseDragged(MouseEvent m)
{
    titlebar.setLocation(m.getXOnScreen() -tx, m.getYOnScreen() -ty);
}
```