# Making a java swing frame movable and setUndecorated

Tags: java, swing

I have created a frame without the title bar, for that I used the setUndecorated(true); method but after that the frame is became unmovable for some reason.

How can I make my frame movable and still hide my title bar?

Comment: The way you move a Swing Frame is by clicking on its title bar and dragging it around.  No title bar implies no movement.  How did you plan to drag it around without a title bar?

Comment: That's the default way, you never saw a program without a title bar which is movable?well I did and I would like to create one :)

Comment: Basically, you need to define an area around the border of the frame that can be "dragged", using a combination of a MouseListerner and MouseMotionListener you need to delta the difference between the click point and the drag point

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following code will create a JFrame without a title bar, which you can still move around:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class FrameDragListenerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");

                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Click anywhere in the Jframe and drag");
                label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(16f));
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
                contentPane.add(label);
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

                FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(frame);
                frame.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
                frame.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private final JFrame frame;
        private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

        public FrameDragListener(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
        }
    }
}
```

You can still drag it around by dragging the body of the frame.

Comment: Comparing component coordinates and screen coordinates is probably not a good idea. You may need to use e.getLocationOnScreen in the mousePressed event as well ;)

Comment: can you do this with jpanels

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will  help you  [Moving Window](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I encapsulate a extended `JFrame` class for you, I called it `MoveaFrame`, you just need to "extend MoveaFrame" in your practice:

Just copy below codes to your project, and extend it, you can make your Frame window draggable!

Extend `MoveJFrame` like extend a `JFrame`, you can directly drag your window:

```java
public class ContactUi extends MoveJFrame implements  Runnable {
```

The `MoveJFrame`  class code, just copy it and extend it like extend `JFrame`:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MoveJFrame extends JFrame {

    public MoveJFrame() {


        this.setUndecorated(true);


        FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(this);
        this.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new MoveJFrame();
    }

    public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private final JFrame frame;
        private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

        public FrameDragListener(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
        }
    }
}
```