# Making a setundecorated, tabbedpane movable

Tags: java, swing, frame, jtabbedpane, movable

I'm making a project for school and having a little problem. I used frames with `setUndecorated` and added code to make it movable using this: [Making a java swing frame movable and setUndecorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046824/making-a-java-swing-frame-movable-and-setundecorated)

It works fine except for one frame where I am using a tabbedpane.

Here's an image explaining it better:
[image: http://gyazo.com/6cea08f42347841a3846bdfffe9e3d71]

Here is my code where I make the tappedpane:

```
    public Main() {

            icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("usericon.png"));
            icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("aboicon.png"));
            icon3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("iconcoin.png"));
            icon4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icongewicht2.png"));

    JTabbedPane jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel Paneel1 = new Paneel1();                
    jtbExample.addTab("Klanten",icon , Paneel1);

    jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);

    JPanel Paneel2 = new Paneel2();
    jtbExample.addTab("Abonnement",icon2, Paneel2);

    JPanel Paneel3 = new Paneel3();
    jtbExample.addTab("Geld opladen",icon3, Paneel3);

    JPanel Paneel4 = new Paneel4();
    jtbExample.addTab("Schema's",icon4, Paneel4);

    // Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jtbExample);

}


}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re adding the Mouse-Listeners to the JPanel, which in your case  is overlapped by the JTabbedPane. Therefore you have to add the Mouse-Listeners to the JTabbedPane.
Just replace the `f.addMouse(Motion)Listener` with `jtbExample.addMouse(Motion)Listener`.

```
    jtbExample.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });

    jtbExample.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            f.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
        }
    });
```